# Why isnt Grid working when the code is working on another project?

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I need to add Cards to my website so I've built a Card component and I added four cards to the Cards component and now I want to position them like this using Grid : 1     2
3      4

> but its not working. Can someone explain to me what am I doing wrong here?

```
HTML
export const Kartolinat = () => {
  return (
    <div className="container">
        <div className="cards-container">
            <Karta 
                className="para"
                imageUrl="url-to-image2.jpg"
                userName="John Doe"
                description="A passionate developer"
            />
            <Karta className="dyta"
                imageUrl="url-to-image2.jpg"
                userName="Jane Smith"
                description="Designer extraordinaire"
            />
            <Karta className="tre"
                imageUrl="url-to-image2.jpg"
                userName="Jane Smith"
                description="Designer extraordinaire"
            />
            <Karta 
                className="kater"
                imageUrl="url-to-image2.jpg"
                userName="Jane Smith"
                description="Designer extraordinaire"
            />
            {/* Add more Card components as needed */}
        </div>
    </div>
  );
};



CSS
.cards-container .card-para {
  grid-area: epara;
}
.cards-container .card-dyta {
  grid-area: edyta;
}
.cards-container .card-treta {
  grid-area: etreta;
}
.cards-container .card-katerta {
  grid-area: ekaterta;
}
.cards-container > div {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 0;
  
}

.cards-container{
  height: 500px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(60px 60px);
  grid-auto-rows:minmax(100px, auto);
  grid-template-areas: "epara epara epara edyta edyta edyta . . ."
  ". . . etreta etreta etreta ekaterta ekaterta ekaterta";
  background-color: lightgray;
  display: grid;
  border: 2px solid black;
  justify-content: start;
}
```

I havent tried anything because I cant target the problem.

Comment: what is exactly not working? are the styles not applied at all? can you make sure you're importing the CSS file in your component?

Comment: The styles are applied because when I remothe css and the grid, the cards go out of shape. But when I apply it, they just line up like this 1 2 3 4